# Wp Ecommerce Reposition Product Page Product Thumbnail Image

Tags: plugins, functions

i want to reposition the product thumbnail of the wp ecommerce plugin product page product images. the default thumbnail function of wp doesnt seem to work

```
add_image_size( 'product-thumbnail', 225, 225, array( 'center', 'top' ) );
add_image_size( 'thumbnail', 225, 225, array( 'center', 'top' ) );
the_post_thumbnail( array(175, 175), FALSE ); 
add_image_size( 'wpsc-product', 175, 175, array( 'center', 'top' ) );
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the product image upload in fullsize then add the code below in functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'thumbnail', 150, 150, array( 'center', 'top' ) );
```